# Changing the name of newsrc.eld

Tags: git, gnus

Is it possible to change the name of Gnus' `newsrc.eld`?

My use-case is that I want to use the same Emacs setup on various machines, which are either work machines or private machines.  The Gnus configurations are different for work and private and kept in separate files, one of which is loaded conditionally.  I'd like to be able to keep, say, `newsrc.work.eld` and `newsrc.private.eld` in Git and then refer to the appropriate file in the corresponding Gnus config.

Comment: Can you use a symlink?

Comment: Yes, I could.  Should have thought of that.  However, it would be nicer if I could actually change the name, because then the configuration would be self-contained. Then I wouldn't have to remember about the symlinks (already not my strong suit, as you see).

Comment: Isn't it a matter of just creating the symlinks once and for all? `newsrc.eld -> newsrs.home.eld` on your home machines and `newswrs.eld -> newsrc.work.eld` on your work machines. Gnus uses `newsrc.eld` on both but it's redirected under its feet. I'm not sure what the difficulty is: you'lll have to remember to create the link on a new machine, but that too can be part of the automation of setting up a new (work or home) machine. I may be misunderstanding your configuration though, so feel free to ignore this.

Comment: I think you have understood correctly what I want to do, it's just that I am being lazy.  Private and work machines probably only change at a rate of about half a dozen over 5-10 years.  That's not often enough to make a lot of automation seem worth while.  On the other hand it is seldom enough for me to forget some of the manual steps I'll need when I have to make the change (as you saw, remembering about symlinks is not my strong suit).

Answer (score 1):

The code that saves the .eld file appends ".eld" to *gnus-current-startup-file*.

Comment: But you can alter the directory gnus-home-directory. and thus the .eld file is in

Comment: Tweaking ```gnus-home-directory``` seems like a good option. With that it seems like I could indeed avoid needing the symlinks.